# Why does this floor function give error by 1

Tags: c++, floor

Why does

```
cout << floor(pow(1000000000,1.0/3))<<nl;
```

give 999? It should be 1000.

This

```
cout << floor(powf(1000000000,1.0/3))<<nl;
```

gives 1000, but I do not understand why the first gives weird answer.

I saw someone having same trouble in sql here:
[I have a question about sql function: floor()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56731512/i-have-a-question-about-sql-function-floor)
But I do not know SQL so I couldn't understand the response.

Comment: In both cases, due to floating point not having infinite precision.  Errors are introduced in both cases.   The only difference, in the second case, is that - on your system - the errors happen to cancel out.

Comment: *It should be 1000* - Why should it?

Comment: If you remove the `floor` and print all the decimals, you will see `999.9999999999996589394868351519107818603515625` and `1000.00018310546875`.